# CSS Ease Transitions on Safari Vs Chrome

Tags: html, css, animation, css-animations

Check out my site on chrome and then safari. Take a look at the banner transition at the top when scroll slightly.

https://www.successpartnersuniversity.com/speakers

```
nav{
    -webkit-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -moz-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -o-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    -ms-transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
    transition: all 0.4s ease-in-out;
}
```

This is quite embarrassing...In chrome and firefox, not a single pixel is skipped in the ease transitions. But on Safari it is horrible... The link is too the speakers page which is the worst but the about page is considerably better.. that is weird also.

I found lots of sites explaining why... I dont care... Does anyone have anything i can do try to make it better?

Thanks!

Comment: try to use `transform: translate3d(x,y,0)` for the translation of the menu from `0vw` to `13.1vw` and declare only those properties which are changing in the transition instead of `all` and maybe you could try to use `will-change`

Comment: Currently `webkit-transition` is not a valid attribute on any `HTML` element, in any browser. Did you mean `-webkit-transition`?

Comment: that was a typo in the question only.

Comment: @Omar Can you edit the question and correct the typo? Otherwise this question will always have the error.

Answer (score 0):

Certain Safari may have a problem with the use of '`all`' I believe. While targeting safari browser, try to use an alternative to '`all`' to achieve your effect.

*Read more:* http://joelglovier.com/writing/solution-for-css-transitions-crashing-safari